# When and who called +initialize?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

My program has a class and that class has an `+initialize` method. I wonder who calls that method? The debugging tools are very unclear:

[image]

What triggers `+initialize` to be called? The beginning of application launch?

Comment: post the code when you use it for the first time

Comment: Actually, the debugging tools tell you exactly who called it: `_class_initialize()`. Your stack traces aren't expanded though, so ultimately you don't know who called *that*. To see, expand the stack traces with the slider at the bottom left of the Xcode window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime sends `initialize` to each class in a program exactly one time just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program.

See the documentation for `+ (void)initialize` on `NSObject`.

An [authoritative blog post](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/) on the question of `initialize` states that `initialize` is executed once when the class is first used, i.e. as the docs state before the class is sent its first message.

Comment: And who send that first message? How do I track it?

Comment: If you are creating instances of the class in question, then you could put a breakpoint on your designated initializer and look at the stack trace.  You would have to override `init` of course.

Comment: I figured out where it's called. However, look at the stack trace in the picture. Doesn't tell a lot isn't it.

Comment: The stack trace is for the `initialize` method which is called by the Objective-C runtime.  Because much of the runtime is opaque to the us, that trace won't tell you very much.  What I was hoping to suggest above was to look at the stack trace for `init` on your class.  Presumably there, it is _your_ code that is calling `init` and you could discern from that who is touching your class first.

Comment: Or put a break point at init :) I found this one in this case anyway.